Is there a way to select the biggest/largest/latest transaction in a list?
If I have a set of transactions and want to pick out the full transaction of the largest or latest transaction, how do I identify and extract that transaction. e.g. given a table like



ID
ItemID
Qty
Value
TranDate
CustID




11254
a123
10
123.60
10/01/2021
FH12AH


11236
a124
1
1123.60
15/01/2021
FH12AH


1123
a129
9
23.10
15/01/2021
FH12AH


11237
a125
5
213.10
15/01/2021
FH12AH


2134
a123
3
37.08
15/01/2021
QB876G


3412
b987
31
123.60
23/01/2021
QB876G


4321
jp34
5
123.60
30/01/2021
JH8765


4322
a123
51
1123.60
02/01/2021
TT6548



how would I extract the entire transaction for

the highest value transaction for each customer

the highest value transaction for each product


I can write a query to extract the date of the highest value of transaction per customer like this:
Select CustID, max(value) as highest_value
from Table
Group By CustID

But to extract the entire transaction, I need to JOIN that to the original table as a subquery, i.e.
select t.*
from Table t
join (
    select CustID, max(value) as highest_value
    from Table
    group By CustID
) sq on t.CustID = sq.CustID 
    and t.value = sq.highest_value

Is there a simpler construct to do the same job?

Sample data is great, but a [mcve] is also supposed to include the expected result.

Look into Row_number with partition by.

You could use a CTE and windowed function instead. if that "simpler" is purely up to your perspective.

SELECT X.* FROM
(
    SELECT T.*,
     ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY T.CustID ORDER BY T.VALUE DESC)AS XCOL 
     FROM YOUR_TABLE AS T
) X WHERE X.XCOL=1

the highest value transaction for each customer

Do we really need a 101st Top 1 in each group answer? If this is the answer, there a VTC/flag as duplicate feature.
